# AWS EC2 windows instance 1/2 status check

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2016

I converted my ec2 instance running on windows server 2016 from m5.large to m6a.large, type change successful,

Problem is:

1. but Instance status checks : failed
2. verified Get instance screenshot, its showing the windows login screen but I am not able to connect with instance.

Comment: What problem are you having? Are you able to log in, and you're just curious about the status check? Did you look at the AWS documentation? There are two status checks, which one failed? Suggest you edit your question to give more information and tell us the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: I converted my ec2 instance running on windows server 2016 from m5.large to m6a.large, type change successful,

Problem is:

 1. but Instance status checks : failed 
 2. verified Get instance screenshot, its showing the windows login screen but I am not able to connect with instance.

Comment: What have you tried? AWS has multiple help articles about this. eg https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstances.html   https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-windows-instance-status-check-fail/    https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-windows-system-status-check-fail/